# What is the Detonator's "flare explosion" and how do I perform one?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-pyro

On the Detonator's wiki [page](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Detonator#Damage_and_function_times),  it says the following under base damage:
[image]

I know that the 30 damage is achieved when the detonator is a direct hit, and the 10-20 damage is achieved when the flare is manually detonated (the damage depending on the distance from the detonated flare to the enemy), but what is a flare explosion?

The wiki page provides no more information than simply "flare explosion: 56 [damage]", so what is a flare explosion, and how do I use one on an enemy?

Answer (score 4):

Shortly after firing a flare from the Detonator, the Pyro can detonate the flare with the alternate-fire keybind. This creates a small explosion that does damage and lights all enemies hit on fire.

The Pyro can also use the detonation to air-jump. From experience, I'd say it gives about as much distance as a single Force-a'-Nature shot.

The damage stat for "flare detonation" that you see is something you can't quite control. If you manually detonate the flare, the damage is from the "flare detonation" stat, whereas if a flare detonates on impact, it deals the "flare explosion" damage.

Comment: I still don't understand. How can I perform a flare explosion on an enemy? The way you've described it, there's no difference between a flare detonation and a flare explosion.

Comment: Ah. Apologies, updated my answer.

Comment: So the flare explosion splash damage is essentially splash damage from the flare gun? In which case, what's the point in the manual detonation if all I have to do is fire my flare reasonably close to the enemy (say, on the ground near him), and let splash damage take care of the rest? This would be 56 damage in comparison to the maximum of 20 damage from the manual detonation.

Comment: Yes, but the explosion radius is *much* smaller if you don't manually detonate.

Comment: Ah, So in order to get the maximum possible damage from the detonator, I should aim it not directly at my enemy, but at their feet, say?